How can I use heterogenous key types with boost::unordered_flat_map
Boost unordered_flat_map is pretty good, it's way faster than std::unordered_map. I'm trying to use it with heterogenous key types:
boost::unordered::unordered_flat_map<std::string, int> my_map;
my_map.emplace(std::string("Hello"), 1);
my_map.find(std::string_view("Hello")); 
// no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list
            argument types are: (std::string_view)

Now, because I created a map that has key type std::string there is a find function that takes a std::string, but there's also a templated find function that takes a K, and usually these things are supposed to work provided the container:


Knows how to hash the heterogenous type, and
Knows of a equality operator that takes the heterogenous type as the right hand side.


Even if I do:
auto equal_to = [](auto& lhs, auto& rhs) { return lhs == rhs; };

And pass this equality class to the container I still get the error:
boost::unordered::unordered_flat_map<std::string, int, decltype(equal_to)> my_map;

How am I supposed to get this to work?

I don't know boost, but I bet you can beat std::unordered_map handily with a bespoke version of whatever you need.

@Jason I've already spent way too long looking at benchmarks of the best ones. So far I've tested the Martinus' Robin Hood map and this Boost unordered_flat_map. I was impressed with the Boost one, I picked it over the robing hood one because it performed slightly better. And they both beat std::unordered_map by a lot, sometimes twice as fast.

Oh interesting, the boost undordered_flat_map is also a Robin Hood hash map.  How about just defining it as boost::unordered::unordered_flat_map<std::string_view, int>, then, store your std::strings out of band?

@Jason Interesting workaround but I don't really like it. I'd have to have to manage multiple lifetimes and possibly reference count, I'm not sure. This should be a really simple solution, pass any type to the find function and if operator == is defined and the hasher can hash it, it's fine.

From cppreference we learn that transparent hash/equality enable heterogenous key lookup:

3,4) Finds an element with key that compares equivalent to the value
x. This overload participates in overload resolution only if
Hash::is_transparent and KeyEqual::is_transparent are valid and each
denotes a type. This assumes that such Hash is callable with both K
and Key type, and that the KeyEqual is transparent, which, together,
allows calling this function without constructing an instance of Key.

So, you might do that:
struct MyHash : std::hash<std::string_view> {
    using is_transparent = std::true_type; // actual type doesn't matter
};

Now, for the equal_to we can be lazy and use std::equal_to</*void*/> which is already transparent:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/unordered/unordered_flat_map.hpp>
using namespace std::literals;

struct MyHash : std::hash<std::string_view> {
    using is_transparent = std::true_type; // actual type doesn't matter
};

int main() {
    boost::unordered::unordered_flat_map<std::string, int, MyHash, std::equal_to<>> my_map;
    auto [where,ok] = my_map.emplace("Hello", 1);
    assert(ok);

    auto found = my_map.find("Hello"sv);
    assert(found != my_map.end());
    assert(found == where);
}

Passing all asserts. In my code I would probably not rely on equal_to<void> to prevent surprises. You could substitute Boost's "Rosetta Stone" core::string_view¹. You could also make the hash even more tolerant (e.g. expressing it in terms of Boost ContainerHash).

¹ which is interoperable among many, like boost::beast::string_view and std::string_view and many others. It does, however, not support configurable char-traits.

Thank you, that's the only thing it needs: add using is_transparent = | ANYTHING |

One more workaround solution, but I need more space =]
You could wrap the lookup in a function (like):
int lookup(std::string_view k) {
    static std::string backing;
    backing = k;
    return my_map.find(backing);
}

Since the std::string is static, it will not continually be allocating and de-allocating every function call.
